# How to check the status of a table in RDS Aurora - MySQL 5.6 read replica

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We have an RDS Aurora - MySQL 5.6 compatible cluster running on AWS.
It has one writer instance, and one read replica.
We want to check the status of a table (see if it's corrupted or not) by running the following command:

```
check table table_name;
```

We can only run this command in the **writer** endpoint, if we run the same command in the **read-only** endpoint, it will hang forever, leaving a query in the processlist (the rest of the output is removed for security reasons);

```
+----+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| id | command | state       | info                        |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+
|  4 | Killed  | System lock | check table table_name      |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

We can't kill this queries using any of these:

```
CALL mysql.rds_kill(4)
CALL mysql.rds_kill_query(4)
```

They don't work. It seems apparently that after running that command (check table table_name), the table will be locked, and it will not allow me to run any further command against that specific table.

AWS support suggested to upgrade the Aurora version, but we tried in 3 different versions, and we see the issue in all of them:

Aurora v1.19.2 (Latest)
Aurora v1.17.8
Aurora v1.16

So the question is, why is this happening?
What is the correct command to check if a table is corrupt or not in Aurora MySQL 5.6?

**Caveat:**
We tried in 3 different clusters, and the issue is in all of them, so obvious advice: don't run this command in your production database.

Comment: Did you check for active queries reading the table? It may be related to long-running queries on the reader instance blocking the Table Definition on the Tables Open Cache mechanism. Accordingly to [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/check-table.html#check-table-innodb): "To avoid timeouts, the semaphore wait threshold (600 seconds) is extended by 2 hours (7200 seconds) for CHECK TABLE operations", so it may hang for a while before aborting.